# HTMLの特定タグ文字列を加工したい

Tags: php, 正規表現

以下のコードを修正、表示したいと思っているのですが私には難解すぎて困っています。

現在PHPで作成したRSSを配信しているのですが、その中で、もともとあるコードを加工したいと思っています。

（例） 
▼現

```
<img class="aa bb cc etc" src="https://hogehoeg.com/○○○.jpg" alt="○○○" width="○○○" height="○○○" />出典：https://△△△.com
```

↓ 
▼改

```
<figure><img src="https://hogehoeg.com/○○○.jpg" alt="○○○" /><figcaption>出典：https://△△△.com</figcaption></figure>
```

上記現から改のように、imgタグのsrcとaltのみを残したまま`<figure>`内に入れ込み、かつ「出典」部分のテキストのみを`<figcaption>`内に入れ込むという正規表現、置き換え方法をご教示いただければ幸いです。

なお、出典直後の「：」は全角（：）と半角（:）の場合があります。

`img`直後は必ず「出典」文字列が付与されていますが改行タグやスペースが入っていることもあります。

`preg_replace`をあれこれ試してみたものの見当違いな結果を連発し、困っています。

Comment: すでにあるPHPプログラムで生成したRSSを、新しく作るPHPプログラムで取得して置換するということでしょうか？すでにあるPHPプログラムの方を変更できれば簡単そうですが、それは出来ないとうことですよね？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/45272 マルチポスト先にて無事解決されたようですが、できれば解決に至った回答をこちらにも投稿して回答の承認を行うとより良いかと思います。